# schema.org markup for voucher codes

Tags: seo, schema.org

I'd like to start using schema.org markup. At the moment I'm trying to mark up voucher codes but I'm a bit lost. I have seen one website that is showing voucher codes as offers:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="40.0%" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/InStock" />
    ...
</div>
```

This approach seems very wrong. How can a coupon code be in stock? And the price can't be forty percent. Funny that this particular website is ranking very well.

But what is the correct way? I can't find a proper item type for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[discount](https://schema.org/discount) only applies to [Order](https://schema.org/Order), which is for completed transactions. Thus there's no real schema designed specifically for separate discount codes.

[Offer](https://schema.org/Offer) seems to be the closest and most appropriate schema for this as you *are* offering a voucher code. Voucher codes can be available or unavailable, with [LimitedAvailability](https://schema.org/LimitedAvailability) and an end date set with [availabilityEnds](https://schema.org/availabilityEnds). For price, you can set [priceSpecification](https://schema.org/priceSpecification).

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. You can't specify a percentage value though.

Comment: @sleepless You can as a Text type for price.

Answer (score 0):

@grgarside, According to [this article](http://www.stateofdigital.com/schema-org-best-practices/), using offer schema for coupon websites should give you a penalty.

As much as I found from my research, there is no property defined for defining a voucher code.
But you stillc can use LimitedAvailability and set your coupon end date with availabilityEnds.